# vCPU/pVCPU Calculation

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell, central-processing-unit, intel

I am trying to calculate the **vCPU/pVCPU** information in [Dell PowerEdge MX740c](https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/Product_Docs/en/poweredge-mx740c-technical-guide.pdf?newtab=true) using the [Intel Xeon Gold 6148 Processor (SKU 6148)](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/120489/intel-xeon-gold-6148-processor-27-5m-cache-2-40-ghz.html) with Hyperthreading.

Does this seems correct?

```
pCPU Calculation
(# Processor Sockets) X (# Cores/Processor)  = # Physical Processors (pCPU)
2 x 20 = 40 pCPU

vCPU Calculation
(# pCPU) X (2 threads/physical processor) = # Virtual Processors (vCPU)
40 x 2 = 80 vCPU
```

Comment: 40 * 2, but the 80 is correct.

Comment: And what is that? You can load 2 virtual cpu for every core may mean they do nothing, or they are totally overloaded.

Comment: @TomTom, this is just [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading), which is fairly standard these days even on consumer machines.

Comment: @SimonRichter This is not what I say. What I say is that the formula means what? A limit on how many you CAN use? SHOULD use? The later is totally depending on what the VM's actually DO.

Comment: Yeah, you'll get 80 addressable CPUs with that processor pair. What happens on VMs is up to the hypervisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you've got two sockets populated.